# OpenCV2 error: (-215:Assertion failed) 'cv::resize' while training the model

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to train my model but I am getting below error. PFB code and error:
**Code:**
***datasets.py***

from numpy import *
import csv
import cv2
#import util

class C100Dataset:
"""
X is a feature vector
Y is the predictor variable
"""
tr_x = []  # X (data) of training set.
tr_y = []  # Y (label) of training set.
ts_x = [] # X (data) of test set.
ts_y = [] # Y (label) of test set.
#filename='cifar100.csv'
def **init**(self, filename):
## read the csv for dataset (cifar100.csv, cifar100_lt.csv or cifar100_nl.csv),
#
# Format:
#   image file path,classname

```
    ### TODO: Read the csv file and make the training and testing set
    ## YOUR CODE HERE
    
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            
            row[0] = row[0].replace('cifar100','./Downloads/dataset/')
            #try
            x = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(row[0]), dsize=(640, 480))
            
            x = transpose(x, (2, 0, 1))
            if 'train' in row[0].split('/'):
                self.tr_x.append(x)
                self.tr_y.append(row[1])
            else:
                self.ts_x.append(x)
                self.ts_y.append(row[1])

def getDataset(self):
    return [self.tr_x, self.tr_y, self.ts_x, self.ts_y]
```

**Error:**

OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-4g0fenxj\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize

Comment: Can you confirm that you are actually reading in an image with `cv2.imread(row[0])`?

Comment: @Davis I am actually referring to a CSV file where we have test and train datapath and we are importing it and trying to split the data.

Comment: I believe that error indicates the `src` for `cv2.imresize` is "empty." I would check that you are successfully reading the image file when you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are reading an image with `cv2.imread(row[0])`. The `!ssize.empty()` indicates the `src` for`cv2.resize` is "empty." I can recreate this same error message with a simple test case

```py
import cv2
cv2.resize(cv2.imread('foobar'), dsize=(640, 480))
```

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\...\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```